# .htaccess redirect to subdomain url with hash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect a site with the following url structure:

`https://example.com/2021/about` 
to
`https://2021.example.com/#about`

`https://example.com/2021/visit` 
to
`https://2021.example.com/#visit`

how can i do this?

i tried adding this to the /about directory in the original domain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)  https://2021.example.com/#about [R=301,NE, L]
```

but what i got after the redirect was
`https://2021.example.com/#about2021/about`

which is not right. any help is appreciated

[EDIT] i only want to apply this to some folders, like /2021/about and 2021/visit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(20\d{2})/(.+?)/?$ https://$1.%1/#$2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure this is your topmost rule in .htaccess and you clear your browser cache before testing this new rule.

Comment: as i mentioned in my edited post, this will affect all folders. but i only want to redirect some folders like  /2021/about and 2021/visit

Comment: `this will affect all folders` - No, it worn't. If you see closely it is matching  `20\d{2}` that means it will only redirect URI starting with `2020/`, 2021/, 2022/` etc.

Comment: If it is always going to be `2021` then rule would be: `RewriteRule ^(2021)/(.+)$ https://$1.%1/#$2 [R=301,L,NE]`

Comment: ok this works but currently i get a trailing slash on the final url 

`https://2021.example.com/#about/`

is it possible to remove the trailing slash in the hash? or is it something that i have to handle on the subdomain?

Comment: Yes that can be addressed. Check my updated answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written based on your shown samples. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Following will only be applied to `2021/about` OR `2021/visit` uris.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(2021)/(about|visit)/?$ http://$1.%1/#$2 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

Comment: if i use this, it will redirect other folders too? i only want some folders only like /2021/about and 2021/visit

Comment: @wsgg, ok could you please check my updated answer and let me know if that helps you.